# Gratis Windows tool to queue disk operations

Tags: windows, gratis, file-management

I am reorganizing my servers drives, while at the same time restoring my old laptop's backups to a new laptop.

I have about a dozen copies of Total Commander running, moving, copying, deleting terabytes of data.

Alas, these operations are manipulating the same 5 or 6 disks, competing for access and causing the disk heads to jump around, causing a massive performance drag.

Does anyone know of a gratis Windows tool to let me set up a queue of copy/move/delete (format would be a bonus, but I can live without it) operations and have them execute sequentially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [Teracopy](https://www.codesector.com/teracopy)

- It can queue move & copy (excluding delete)
- pause & resume the operation
- do something after process done (e.g shutdown/hibernate the pc)
- choose what to do when there is same file name, shows version date & file size
- and some other things that I haven't discovered it

Paid version can also skip/remove files that is not processed yet

Comment: Lolx! I actually own TeraCopy, but had forgotten about that, and, D'oh! Total Commander, which I also own can queue operations and can integrate TeraCopy. Great answer, welcome aboard :-)

Comment: @Mawg glad I can help :)